# Linux editor with VMS EDT like direction mode

Tags: software-rec, editors, openvms

VMS editor EDT allows one to use the keypad to control most of ones editing commands. One of the rather nice features is that the direction of operation can be set to "up" or "down". This then effects commands like "move to next character" and "move to start of line". Another feature is that there are "character", "word" and "line" buffers that one can cut, copy and paste to/from.

I am looking for a Linux editor that has these features?

This is not a request for an EDT editor for Linux. I am "willing" to learn a new editor if
it has these features.

Answer (score 10):

You want `emacs`.

`Emacs` has an EDT emulation mode (`M-x edt-emulation-mode`). This will set up `emacs` to use the edt keymappings.

Before you can use it, run `emacs -q -l edt-mapper`. This will let you set up what keys on **YOUR** keyboard map to the various VT keys(`gold`, `do`, etc.).

It works quite well, and you have the extra functionality of `emacs`, plus the edt keys you're used to.

EDIT: I should look at dates, this was asked ages ago... but the information is still good.

Answer (score 8):

[Vim](http://vim.org) seems to provide all those features. There are plenty of good tutorials for it on the web, but the easiest way to familiarise yourself with the editor is to install it and then run the `vimtutor` program supplied.

<kbd>H</kbd> - Left
<kbd>J</kbd> - Down
<kbd>K</kbd> - Up
<kbd>L</kbd> - Right

<kbd>4L</kbd> - 4 characters right
<kbd>4W</kbd> - 4 words right

<kbd>0</kbd> - Start of line
<kbd>$</kbd> - End of line
<kbd>gg</kbd>- Start of file
<kbd>GG</kbd>- End of file
<kbd>100gg</kbd> - Line 100

Comment: @C W Holeman II: I'm just going to edit the answer with that. Sorry about the long delay :)

Comment: Note that EDT has a direction mode so that rather than LLWW, EDT would use: Down AdvChar AdvChar AdvWord AdvWord and rather than HH, EDT would use: Up AdvChar AdvChar. EDT also uses the arrow keys rather than HJKL.

Comment: Vim also allows you to use the arrow keys - but using HJKL is supposedly faster if you type properly, as they are in the home row. I, however, do not type properly, so I find the arrow keys just as fast.

Answer (score 3):

Emacs's [Picture mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Picture-Mode.html) is designed to facilitate drawing ASCII diagrams and tables. You can change the direction in which the cursor moves after inserting a character with `C-c left`, `C-c down`, etc.

Comment: "Move left after insertion" looks like it is specific to just the action after a character is inserted.